# How to adjust display colors in elementary OS

Tags: display, gnome

How can I adjust the display color on elementary OS? They only offer predefined profiles that I can set my monitor to, but I can't calibrate any of them. I already have gnome color manager and icc installed.

I want to adjust contrast, red, green, and blue levels, and etc.

**EDIT:** I figured it out, use xgamma(obsolete see xrandr solution below) command. I didn't realize the magnitude of numbers represents color contrast as well as adjusting color hue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify gamma settings (colors and effectively contrast too) using `xrandr` tool.

---

First determine the output name of your monitor:

For example:

```
ravan@ravan:~$ xrandr -q | grep connected
VGA1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 410mm x 230mm
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

In the above example I have a monitor connected and seen as output **VGA1**.

---

Using `xrandr`

From man page of `xrandr` (See `man xrandr`)

> Xrandr is used to set the size, orientation and/or  reflection  of  the
>          outputs for a screen. It can also set the screen size.

command:

```
xrandr --output [DISPLAY_NAME] --gamma [R_VALUE]:[G_VALUE]:[B_VALUE]
```

Example:

```
xrandr --output VGA1 --gamma 1.28:1:1.28 # for purple
```

In the above example gamma values are in format `Red`:`Green`:`Blue`

See [here](http://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/RGB_Color.htm) for corresponding numeric values for  RGB colors.

In RGB color table, see decimal code and  if you have 128 then use 1.28

*EDIT*:

If you want to revert then use: `1:1:1` to restore the default state.

*EDIT*: (tested on freya)

To make changes permanent, add the script to start-up applications.

Open terminal and run:

```
nano  monitor_display.sh
```

Add the following lines.

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 50
xrandr --output VGA1 --gamma 1.28:1:1.28 #same command you used previously.
```

Now Ctrl+X --> Y--> ENTER.

Now run:

```
chmod +x monitor_display.sh
```

Now to add to startup applications:

Open system settings --> applications --> startup --> click on **+** and add the command:

```
/bin/bash monitor_display.sh
```

Now reboot.

*Note*: You will see custom command `.desktop` file in `~/.config/autostart`

Comment: Also, how do you make the gamma settings permanent? It resets to 1:1:1 after reboot.

Comment: I read in the Ubuntu forum that you can save a xorg.conf file in "etc/x11", but I don't have an xorg.conf already so I tried to make one and I didn't have permission. The link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/63681/how-can-i-make-xrandr-customization-permanent

Comment: @Dobob I will add in few minutes. I have to test before post, :)

Comment: @Dobob I have edited my answer :) please let me know

Comment: It works. I did change "sleep 50" to "sleep 5". The only downside is that "xrandr --verbose -q" returns inaccurate gamma settings. I have set my gamma to "1.0 : 0.93 : 1.0", but xrandr reports "1.0: 1.1: 1.0". Any way to check current gamma settings? It seems that xrandr uses approximated gamma and brightness settings, whereas "xgamma" doesn't.

Comment: read `man xgamma`.Also sleep 5 will not work. Even though it seems working, its not. After few seconds, the effect will be reverted to default. I have even tried with `30`. If you want to change try more than 30

Comment: That's not happening to me. I have "sleep 5" and it hasn't reverted back.

Comment: Thats cool :) @Dobob

Comment: Actually I discovered that by deleting a folder from my USB causes the monitor display to revert back to a gamma of 1.0:1.0:1.0. What is going on? This is so weird.

Answer (score 0):

Try DisplayCal https://displaycal.net/

You can both calibrate, and assign profiles to a display. Download the package, install with a package manager (e.g. Eddy) and then run DisplayCal app. To assign a profile, go to **File >> Install display device profile**

You can also calibrate using that tool too if you have a compatible colorimeter (it supports many third party ones).