# xrandr and xgamma settings reverted after deleting random files and suspending computer

Tags: display, folder

After following the instructions here:
[How to adjust display colors in elementary OS](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/3679/how-to-adjust-display-colors-in-elementary-os)

I saved xrandr settings by making run it as a startup application. The settings I set for gamma automatically revert to default after deleting random fold(weird). Is this a bug?

**EDIT:** This actually happens if you set using xgamma or xrandr as startup application or set them through the terminal. You can set xgamma and xrandr through terminal and then delete any random folder and it will also cause gamma settings set through xrandr to revert back to default. But this only happens once per startup. After setting gamma again and then deleting folders won't cause gamma to revert to default.

Scenarios where gamma reverts to default:

1. Deleting random files after initially setting gamma through either xrandr or xgamma. After that if you set the gamma through xrandr or xgamma again, it no longer reverts back to default gamma values; this only happens for the first time you delete a folder or file.
2. Each time you set gamma through xrandr or xgamma, suspend the computer, unsuspend the computer, then log back into your desktop and your gamma will revert to default.

Comment: "deleting files" what are they?

Comment: It happens when deleting any folder.

Comment: What is sleep time? I guess [this](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/3679/how-to-adjust-display-colors-in-elementary-os#comment6424_3685) may be reason?

Comment: I tried with sleep time 5 and 50, deleting any random folder causes the gamma to revert to default. That's why I am trying to find another way of setting gamma persistently.

Comment: I can't reproduce this, can you provide more details. The script in the link is working fine for me.

Comment: Actually it happens regardless of whether you set xrandr as a startup application or not. I set xrandr to my preferred gamma setting through terminal and deleting folders sill causes gamma to revert to default. However this only happens once. After the first time If you set the gamma settings again and delete more folders after that it doesn't revert back.

Comment: I can confirm this now!

Comment: So I am assuming this is a bug and there is currently no fix? I can't find any alternative solution that works.

Comment: I didn't understand. What do you mean? You do the procedure, and then if you type "mkdir anyfolder" and "rm -r anyfolder/" your changes are reverted? is that right?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a little bug - actually appearing in freya. I can't reproduce this in Ubuntu.

I decided to file a bug report on [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-greeter/+bug/1531386).

*Please may everybody reading this and having observed the same behaviour
confirm this bug to increase its importance and get it fixed quickly! Thank you.*

To do this, click the link above, log into your launchpad account and click on:
*This bug affects X people. Does this bug affect you?* - Select "Yes"

Comment: did this happen to you?

Comment: @Aleksandrus I am the OP (answer)  to the linked post.  [yes](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/3785/xrandr-and-xgamma-settings-reverted-after-deleting-random-files/3867?noredirect=1#comment6503_3785). you can read comments above :)